# pygame.camera.init() import error

Tags: python, camera, pygame, importerror

I'm getting an import error when I try to import the camera module from `pygame` in python. I'm using Pycharm.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
line 6, in <module>
    pygame.camera.init()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'camera'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code is -

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame, sys

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

pygame.camera.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))

cam.start()

while True:

    image = cam.get_image()

    screen.blit(image,(0,0))

    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Try - `import pygame.camera` .

Comment: After trying that i get this error: ImportError: cannot import name _camera

Comment: Which line do you get that?

Comment: line 7, in <module>
    pygame.camera.init() and line 42, in init
    from pygame import _camera

Comment: Please update the traceback in the question. Also, seems like your dependencies are not correctly installed, you will need to first install a dependency of either python opencv, or vidcap from http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Are you running this on windows?